# No option to print in black and white in Document Viewer (Evince)

Tags: printing

I swear I used to be able to select colour output in 12.10 but I'm working in 12.04 now and I simply can't figure out how to adjust the colour for printing.  Seems like that option has disappeared.

Comment: Are you sure? You say that it was in 12.10 and _not_ present in 12.04? Then why don't you use 12.10?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't use 12.10.  It's a work PC and they switched me to 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

I was not finding the option on the GUI for an Epson XP-202, but I found it on the command line.

See the printer options with:

```
lpoptions -l
```

It gave me:

```
PageSize/Paper Size: 4X6FULL T4X6FULL 2L T2L *A4 TA4 L TL Postcard TPostcard INDEX5
MediaType/Media Type: PMPHOTO_NORMAL PLATINA_NORMAL GLOSSYPHOTO_NORMAL GLOSSYCAST_NORMAL PMMATT_NORMAL *PLAIN_NORMAL RCPC_NORMAL
Ink/Ink: *COLOR MONO
```

`Ink=MONO` looks good, so I set it with:

```
lpoptions -o Ink=MONO
```

And then when I print with:

```
lp a.pdf
```

it works.

It is a shame that there is no standard CUPS option for that. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18323/how-do-i-make-blackwhite-the-default

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your printer driver. Some people say that they have the setting, others don't. Hopefully you can find a newer printer driver. Maybe your 12.04 install is not compatible with the latest driver or you have chosen to use the open source drivers instead of the proprietary drivers from your printer's manufacturer? The proprietary drivers probably have more features.

[Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/173860) is someone's bug report about not seeing where to change the colour settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but in my case Okular was having troubles to find the black & white option. So I tried Evince: Evince had no problem to find the black & white option (same printer, same driver). Then, I print one page, and tried Okular again: the option appeared!

I have the feeling that some options related to the driver need some contact with the printer to work. Like printing a mock white page (ok, it's a bit stupid), or maybe a simple ping or scan is enough, I'm not sure (it may be required to restart Okular, I'm also not sure). I don't know yet if Evince always works directly or if I just got luck due to previous "contacts" made by Okular, but for sure Okular has some troubles.